# How to read data in response of POST operation using jersey client (RestFull)

Tags: java, rest-client, jersey-client

In my java client application, I am accessing a endpoint URL and could able to get response back, but it is in HTML code!.

Method : Post

```
resource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);

WebResource resource = Client.create().resource(
                communicatorVO.getTargetURL());
String **response** = resource.queryParams(communicatorVO.getFormData()).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).post(String.class, gson.toJson(communicatorVO.getRequestObject()));
```

The response object always contains HTML code! How to get the actual data?

If I try using chrome restful client, am getting below response.

{ 
    "access_token" : "YOUR_NEW_ACCESS_TOKEN",
    "token_type" : "bearer",
    "expires_in" : 10800,
    "refresh_token" : "YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN",
    "scope" : "write read offline_access"
}

Comment: Take a look at [this link](http://harryjoy.com/2012/09/08/simple-rest-client-in-java/) there is an example of using jersey to post data. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved.

I added type & accept in single line and it started returning expected json response. Now I can parse the json into any java object.

Code :

```
response = resource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).post(ClientResponse.class, communicatorVO.getFormData());;
```